# Why isn't my actor receiving a message?

Tags: f#, akka.net

**Issue:**

I am struggling to understand why my Reporter actor is not receiving messages based on the following statement that's in my Generator actor:

```
reporter <! Message input
```

**My reporter actor is the following:**

```
let reporterActor (mailbox:Actor<_>) =

    let rec loop() = actor { let! msg = mailbox.Receive()
                             match msg |> box :?> Command with
                             | Start     -> ()
                             | Message v -> printf "%s" v
                             | Exit      -> mailbox.Context.System.Terminate() |> ignore }
    loop() |> ignore
```

Basically, a console is launched that accepts input from the user. My Generator actor forwards that input to my Reporter actor. However, the code above never gets executed.

**The code is the following:**

```
module Main

open System
open Akka.FSharp
open Akka.Actor
open Actors

type Command = 
    | Message of string
    | Start | Exit

let reporterActor (mailbox:Actor<_>) =

    let rec loop() = actor { let! msg = mailbox.Receive()
                             match msg |> box :?> Command with
                             | Start     -> ()
                             | Message v -> printf "%s" v
                             | Exit      -> mailbox.Context.System.Terminate() |> ignore }
    loop() |> ignore


let generatorActor (reporter:IActorRef) (mailbox:Actor<_>) message =

    let handle input = match input with
                       | "exit" -> mailbox.Context.System.Terminate |> ignore
                       | _      -> reporter <! Message input

    handle (Console.ReadLine().ToLower())

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let system =         System.create "system"         (Configuration.load())
    let reporterActor =  spawn system  "reporterActor"  (actorOf(reporterActor))
    let generatorActor = spawn system  "generatorActor" (actorOf2(generatorActor reporterActor))

    generatorActor <! Start
    system.AwaitTermination ()
    0
```

**Update:**

I learned that I could trigger my Reporter actor by replacing the mailbox parameter with an arbitrary message parameter:

```
let reporterActor message =
     match message |> box :?> Command with
     | Start     -> ()
     | Message v -> printf "Reporting: %s" v
     | Exit      -> failwith "Kill this!"
```

I still don't understand when I should use a mailbox parameter versus when I should rely on a message parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in how actorOf and actorOf2 work.

actorOf in conjunction with spawn creates an actor as a child of the root of the system which will handle messages with the function `'Message -> unit` that was passed to it.

actorOf2 in in conjunction with spawn creates an actor as a child of the actor that you passed in and the child will handle the messages with the function `'Message -> unit` that was passed.

Your original function signature for reporter actor was:

```
Actor<'Message> -> unit
```

and you used `spawn system  "reporterActor"  (actorOf(reporterActor))`

In this case you were saying that the message type that the new actor that was created would receive would be of type `Actor<'Message>` .   This compiled because actorof just expects a function that takes a 'Message, and a 'Message is generic therefore `Actor<'Message>` satisfied the 'Message parameter.

When you updated the signature of reporterActor you change the signature to `'Message -> unit`  which is what actorOf is actually intended to accept.

In short generics allowed your code to compile since 'Message isn't really restricted, nor should it really be.

From: http://getakka.net/docs/FSharp%20API

> actorOf `(fn : 'Message -> unit) (mailbox : Actor<'Message>) :
>   Cont<'Message, 'Returned>` - uses a function, which takes a message as
>   the only parameter. Mailbox parameter is injected by spawning
>   functions.
>
> `actorOf2 (fn : Actor<'Message> -> 'Message -> unit) (mailbox :
>   Actor<'Message>) : Cont<'Message, 'Returned>` - uses a function, which
>   takes both the message and an Actor instance as the parameters.
>   Mailbox parameter is injected by spawning functions. Example:
>
> ```
> > let handleMessage (mailbox: Actor<'a>) msg =
> >     match msg with
> >     | Some x -> printf "%A" x
> >     | None -> ()
> > 
> > let aref = spawn system "my-actor" (actorOf2 handleMessage) let
> > blackHole = spawn system "black-hole" (actorOf (fun msg -> ()))
> ```
>
> spawn (actorFactory : IActorRefFactory) (name : string) (f :
>   Actor<'Message> -> Cont<'Message, 'Returned>) : IActorRef - spawns an
>   actor using a specified actor computation expression. The actor can
>   only be used locally.
>
> All of these functions may be used with either the actor system or the
>   actor itself. In the first case the spawned actor will be placed under
>   /user root guardian of the current actor system hierarchy. In the
>   second option the spawned actor will become a child of the actor used
>   as the actorFactory parameter of the spawning function.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Do you have experience testing actors as well?

Comment: I don't, but I found this link https://petabridge.com/blog/how-to-unit-test-akkadotnet-actors-akka-testkit/ it might be helpful with testing.  I'm not sure if there is an F# -ified library for it or not, but I'm sure you could get it working with F#.